# Returning dynamic table from function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a function `public.find_abc(tablename ANYELEMENT,data text)` in `postgresql` where in `tablename` I will pass the `tablename` and in `data` I will pass the `column names`.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.find_abc(tablename ANYELEMENT,data text)
        RETURNS SETOF  ANYELEMENT  AS
    $body$
    declare 
    new_names   character varying(255)='';
    new_data character varying(255);
    BEGIN
    
    SELECT STRING_AGG (column_name,',') non_encrypted_column  into new_names 
      FROM information_schema.columns
     WHERE table_schema = 'public'
       AND table_name=||tablename|| and column_name not in (||text||);
    
    new_data=upper(text);
    
        RETURN QUERY
        SELECT new_names,new_data
        FROM   ||tablename|| g1;
       
    END;
    $body$   
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select * from public.find_abc('company','name');
```

I looked `RETURNS TABLE(column_name datatype,......)` but here I need to expicitly include all table columns in return statement which is not dynamic(since every table will have different columns) ,so I want to return all column name of that table and  `new_data` which is modified using `UPPER` function to that column when I will pass the values of `public.find_abc('tablename','column_name')` into this function.

Comment: 1) Why `new_data=upper(text);`? 2) Why `column_name not in (||text||);` and then add back the columns with `new_data=upper(text);`  **Add answers as update to question**

Comment: i just want to do specific transfomation for that specific column that is passed in parameter:  upper(text)

Comment: 1) You need to spend some time here [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) 2) This `upper(text)` is going to get folded to lower case in the query per [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).