# How to use variable data inside refcursor in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function in postgresql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.find_n( vref_cursor  refcursor)
returns   refcursor  as
$$
declare 
namess  text;

BEGIN

SELECT STRING_AGG (column_name,',') non_encrypted_column into namess 
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_schema = 'public'
   AND table_name   = 'company' and column_name not in ('id','salary');

OPEN vref_cursor  FOR
SELECT namess from  company;
    RETURN vref_cursor ;

END;
$$   
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

BEGIN;
SELECT public.find_n('vref_cursor');
FETCH ALL IN vref_cursor; 
COMMIT;
```

I hava a table `company` which has these columns:

```
id, name, age, address, salary, join_date
```

The `namess` variable will  ignore `id,salary` column and store:

```
"name,age,address,join_date"
```

When I try to use this sql statment in `refcursor`, `SELECT namess from  company;` I get this:

[image]

I have `5` datas and it is displaying the content of `namess` variable.Rather I need the output of  `SELECT  name, age, address, join_date FROM public.company;` using `refcursor`, so I used `SELECT namess from  company;` but it is not working. How can I get the data of table for these columns `name, age, address, join_date` rather than seeing the dummy data of the variable ?

Comment: You want to look up "EXECUTE" in the pl/pgsql section of the docs. This requires a dynamic query.

Comment: i am aware of dynamic queries but I am confuse how can I use dynamic queries after OPEN vref_cursor  FOR... ?

Comment: 1) This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76263314/returning-dynamic-table-from-function-in-postgresql) says you are not familiar with dynamic queries. 2) You have also not actually looked at the [plpgsql cursor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html) docs, in particular section *43.7.2.2.*. You need to spend time actually reading the documentation.

Comment: Yes, I added this statement OPEN vref_cursor  FOR Execute 'SELECT '+namess+' from  company'; but it is showing me : HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: You used the wrong operator for string concatenation.

Comment: I used this OPEN vref_cursor  FOR Execute ('SELECT %I ',namess,' from company'); but the output is showing ("SELECT %I ","name,age,address,join_date                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "," from company") .. please help me on this i am really stuck on this

Comment: Stop flailing about. Get yourself a fresh cup of tea or coffee, read the docs and get to grips with the syntax.

Comment: i did it anyhow thanks for your tym